Using Surface Analysis for Optimal Plot Division in Parametric Design
In parametric urban design, I faced a challenge with dividing irregularly shaped plots—particularly those with "bottleneck" areas. Instead of traditional methods, I explored an approach by transforming the distances between points along the boundary into Z-values to create a 3D surface. The goal was to locate the lowest points on this surface, representing minimal distances between sections of the plot, while ignoring the central "canyon" of the surface where the distance between mirrored points is zero.
This approach allowed me to analyze the surface's topography to identify bottleneck areas by focusing on valleys outside the main diagonal depression. It’s a bit unconventional, but I found that viewing the problem as a 3D surface opened up new ways to optimize plot divisions effectively.
Has anyone used similar surface analysis methods for geometric partitioning, or are there other strategies for this kind of spatial optimization? I’d appreciate any insights or references!
Thank you!
detail.I've included a link to my LinkedIn post with an animation that illustrates the process in more

Great illustration! Wish you embedded it into your post here, but okay. In your 3d plot, x is the signed arclength from the initial point, z is the chord, and y is the offset of the initial point, right? Maybe it's explained in you LinkedIn post but it's an unfamiliar (to my free DeepL) language. Next, I'm trying to understand what you might mean by "mirror points"... It is interesting though!

Thank you! You’ve understood it perfectly—that’s exactly how the surface are set up.
To answer your question: for any two points, say A and B, there are two straight-line paths between them—one from A to B and one from  B to A . This means that at both points X = A, Y = B and X = B, Y = A, the distance (or height on the surface) will be the same. Thus, the line X = Y serves as a mirror axis for the two halves of the plot.
Unfortunately, I wasn’t able to embed the animation directly into the post, and I apologize for that.
